# Does CO2 dissolution in different salt concentrations affects the amount of carbonic acid formed?

Tags: water, solubility, titration

We have a school experiment, where I must report on the following question:

> Does salinity affect the solubility of $\ce{CO2}$ in saltwater?

So we selected four different concentrations of salt (in the range of 1-4 %) in 100 mL of water and added 5 g of $\ce{CO2}$ and measured the time it took to dissolve completely. We then used titration to figure out the amount of $\ce{CO2}$ (reacting with water to give weak carbonic acid) that is dissolved.

My questions are:

1. Will the amount of $\ce{CO2}$ that reacts with water depend upon the salt concentration?
2. Will the amount of titrant used to figure out the amount of $\ce{CO2}$ dissolved also change depending on the salt concentrations?

Comment: If you expect an answer, you should give your guesses (ooops, hypothesis) to the questions.

Comment: It seems like you did the experiment. Why even ask the question? Just analyse the data you got.

Answer (score 2):

> 100 mL of water and added 5 g of $\ce{CO2}$ and measured the time it took to dissolve completely

This statement doesn't make sense.  Firstly, if you know it dissolved completely, why try to determine how much dissolved?  Secondly, the only way that much CO2 would dissolve is if you did the experiment at high pressure.

If you want literature data to compare your experiment to, see Fig. 6c or equation 6 of [Behaviour of the CO2-H2O system](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjumrbY-r_JAhUJzGMKHTaiBDEQFgghMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.co2-cato.org%2Fcato-download%2F486%2F20090917_123324_4.1-3-05_Behaviour_of_the_CO2-H2O_system.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEu96NCBcEgZdY_SdKT9CovKOeqgw&bvm=bv.108538919,d.cGc)